# How can I prevent "cannot read properties of undefined" error when loading a page with preloaded data in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a code that is supposed to preload some data into my form in Angular, the logic to retrieve this data seems to work but only on random occasions ie. if a delay occurs in my network connection and the api request data doesn't get loaded and stored in time, then Angular throws the error "Cannot read properties of undefined id" in console, I tried converting the ngoninit and the api service get request service into an async await format but it doesn't seem to have any effect on my code, my aim is to ensure that the setValue feature should not be called unless and until the data from the api has been stored completely. I am new to the concept of async programming and would be grateful to have  some help here

```
 async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.form = this.rootForm.control;

    await this.apiService
      .getRequest('customer/category/all', true, false)
      .subscribe(async(res: any) => {
        if (res.success) {
          if (res.data) {
            this.allCategories = await res.data; //this data needs to be loaded completely before the setValue takes place
             
              const selectedCategory = this.allCategories.find(cat => cat.id == 
              this.form.get('category').value);
              
              this.categoryCtrl.setValue(selectedCategory);

              this.prepoluateAdditionalInfo(selectedCategory?.id);
            
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: In angular you should use Observables and not promises or sync/await.
also I don't think you can make ngOnInit async. You have a logical error in your code

Answer (score 0):

The way this is coded is different from what I would expect in Angular.

Can't you refactor it to:

```
this.apiService.getRequest(...)
   .subscribe((res)=>{

   const selectedCategory = this.allCategories
      .find(cat => cat.id == this.form.get('category').value);
   this.categoryCtrl.setValue(selectedCategory);
   this.prepoluateAdditionalInfo(selectedCategory?.id);
})
```

The data (res) will be there completely when you enter in subscribe().